# Как удалить определенную таблицу на гугл диске?

Tags: javascript, google-drive

Есть определённая таблица результатов ,которая сохраняется на гугл диске ,но чтобы таких таблиц не было десятки ,нам нужно перед созданием новой удалить старую с таким же названием , вот мой код,но что-то не так с ним , не могу понять что ?

```
    function deleteFile() {
     var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
     while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      var fname = file.getName();
      if (fname == 'ResultSpread') {
       var id = file.getId();
       Drive.Files.remove(id);
      }
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение :

```
function deleteFile() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fname = file.getName();
    if (fname == 'ResultSpread') {
      var id = file.getId();
      DriveApp.getFileById(id).setTrashed(true);
    }
  }
}
```